# Как отключить редактор для WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как отключить редактор для WordPress ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте только одна странице. Буду сажать лендинг на WordPress. Изначально там стоял Гутенберг но его убрал плагином.

Comment: Кастомный тип поста, не? Блоки гутенберг, как раз идеально подходят для создания лендингов и в т.ч. для создания подобного вида табов. Делал идентичную задачу с помощью https://getblocklab.com и гутенберга. И ничего не пришлось отключать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но нужно сделать именно так как на скрине.

Comment: а зачем вообще отключать ? че муляет ?

Comment: Да мешает. Заказчик попросил убрать и оставить только то с чем работает

Comment: Вот что получилось http://prntscr.com/oplevw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [remove_post_type_support()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_post_type_support/)

Самый простой способ применения:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor'); // первый аргумент - тип поста (post, page и т. д.)
});
```

Убирать гутенберг плагином в таком случае не требуется

Comment: Отлично спасибо !